Compiling C Library Using GMP on Windows
I'm not a programmer, just writing some code for personal use from time to time, so I don't have much experience and knowledge. I'm using CMake and gcc/g++ on Linux or clang on Android (in Termux). Since, I only used those compilers (which have much the same flags), I wrote CMake code to accept only them (I noticed that MSVC has different flags, so, I just didn't spend my time on it).
Recently, I wrote a dynamic C library which uses the GMP library (GMP is linked statically, so, the library can be used on another desktop, without need of installing GMP). But there was a need to compile it on Windows, so, my mate could use the it too. I spent 2 days reading all information I've found and trying to compile it, but without luck. I tried using Visual Studio 2022 and Visual Studio Code with the MSVC compiler but it looked like a completely different workflow to me. I tried using vcpkg but still wasn't able to compile the library (I just aborted the compilation process after waiting more than 1 hour… On Linux it compiled for less than 10 seconds). Switching to another library, like MPIR, didn't look good to me (don't want to rewrite the existing code).
Finally, I managed to compile the DLL library for Windows. Below, I'll provide some initial (Linux) dummy code (for the sake of simplicity), the steps that I took to compile the library, and describe what I changed for Windows.
I'm posting this for the following reasons:

I hope that the information will useful for others who will struggle with similar problems.
It'd be great to get other solutions, recommendations, etc. E.g., how to make the code and process of compilation of static/dynamic libraries cross-platform?

Update
Moved the solution I came up with (not the best, I think) to the answers.

Better would be to edit this into two parts: a question and an answer. It's fine to answer your own question on this site.

Initially I thought to do as you say, but since I think that my solution is not very good, I decided to leave it in the question section. Maybe someone provide better solution.

That's why I suggested it. Lots of good questions have multiple answers but no one wants to answer a long question that already contains the answer.

@stark, updated per you suggestion.

Example code and steps of my solution are below.
Project structure:
dll
├src
│├test
││├test.h
││└test.c
│├main.c
│└main.py
├build.sh
└CMakeLists.txt

Initial project files (for Linux)
test.h:
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <gmp.h>

void Double(mpz_t a);
void Triple(mpz_t a);

#endif  // TEST_H

test.c:
#include "test.h"

#include <gmp.h>

void Double(mpz_t a) { mpz_mul_ui(a, a, 2UL); }
void Triple(mpz_t a) { mpz_mul_ui(a, a, 3UL); }


main.c:
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "test/test.h"

#include <gmp.h>

bool Mult(const char* const val, const char op) {
  mpz_t num;
  mpz_init_set_str(num, val, 0);
  gmp_printf(" In: %Zi\n", num);
  if (op == 'd') { Double(num); }
  else if (op == 't') { Triple(num); }
  else {
    printf("Invalid argument!\n");
    mpz_clear(num);
    return false;
  }
  gmp_printf("Out: %Zi\n", num);
  mpz_clear(num);
  return true;
}

main.py:
import ctypes
import os
import platform

def GetFunction():
  osys = platform.system()
  lib_path = r'/home/linux/Documents/tests/dll/cmake_build'
  lib_path = os.path.join(lib_path, 'libtest.')
  if osys == 'Windows': lib_path += 'dll'
  else: lib_path += 'so'
  lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path)
  lib.Mult.restype = ctypes.c_bool
  lib.Mult.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char]
  return lib.Mult

if __name__ == '__main__':
  mult = GetFunction()
  big_num = 12345678901234567890
  big_num = f'{big_num}'.encode('ascii')
  op = 't'.encode('ascii')
  mult(big_num, op)

build.sh:
#!/bin/bash

n_args=$#
if [ $n_args -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Illegal number of parameters!"
  exit 1
fi

BLD='cmake_build'
BIN='libtest.so'

set -e  # Exit on error.

[ -d "$BLD" ] || mkdir "$BLD"  # Create build dir.
cd "$BLD"
[ -f "$BIN" ] && rm "$BIN"  # Delete compiled file.

# Build and run.
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
cmake --build .

cd ..

CmakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(pref "lib_")  # Prefix.
project(${pref}test)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS OFF)

string(LENGTH ${pref} len)
string(SUBSTRING ${PROJECT_NAME} ${len} -1 out_name)
string(REPLACE "_" "" out_name ${out_name})
string(REPLACE "_" "" lib_name ${PROJECT_NAME})
unset(len)

string(TOLOWER "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" conf_build_type)
string(TOLOWER "Debug" conf_debug)
string(TOLOWER "Release" conf_release)
if(NOT conf_build_type MATCHES "^(${conf_debug}|${conf_release})$")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Unknown build configuration (\"${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}\")!")
endif()

set(comp_gnu "GNU")
set(comp_clang "Clang")
if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL comp_gnu)
  set(COMPILER_VERSION_REQD "13.0.0")
elseif(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL comp_clang)
  set(COMPILER_VERSION_REQD "17.0.0")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "\tNot supported compiler (${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID})!")
endif()
if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS COMPILER_VERSION_REQD)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Version ${COMPILER_VERSION_REQD} or higher required!")
endif()

message("\t${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID} ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION} "
    "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} ${lib_name}")

string(CONCAT flags "-W;-Wall;-Wextra;-Wpedantic;-Wconversion;"
    "-Werror=return-type;-Wsign-conversion")
if(CONF_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL conf_debug)
  string(CONCAT flags "${flags}" ";-O0;-g")
  string(CONCAT flags "${flags}" ";-fsanitize=address")
  add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${flags}>")
  add_link_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-fsanitize=address>")
elseif(CONF_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL conf_release)
  string(CONCAT flags "${flags}" ";-Ofast")
  add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${flags}>")
endif()

set(proj_fpath "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/")
set(exec_path "${proj_fpath}src/")
add_library(${lib_name} SHARED
    "${exec_path}main.c"
    "${exec_path}test/test.c")
target_include_directories(${lib_name} PRIVATE "${exec_path}")
target_link_libraries(${lib_name} PRIVATE gmp)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static")

set_target_properties(${lib_name} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "${out_name}")

Steps that helped to solve the problem

Installed MSYS2.
Ran the MSYS2 MINGW64 shell and installed the following:

CMake: pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake;
GMP: pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp.


Navigated to the project root folder.
Modified the C code in main.c for DLL compilation.
Modified build.sh to include proper compiled library extension (.dll for Windows).
Modified CmakeLists.txt to specify paths to GMP header and compiled library:

C:\msys64\mingw64\include for gmp.h;
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib: for libgmp.a and libgmp.dll.a.


In the MSYS2 MINGW64 shell, ran ./build.sh to compile the library and closed the shell.
Modified main.py to include proper compiled library path.
Ran PowerShell or Command Prompt.
Navigated to main.py folder.
Ran the python3 main.py command.

Modified portions of project files (for Windows)
main.c:
...
#include <gmp.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
  #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define DLLEXPORT
#endif  // _WIN32

DLLEXPORT bool Mult(const char* const val, const char op) {
...

main.py:
...
  osys = platform.system()
  lib_path = r'C:\Users\Linux\diff\dll\cmake_build'
  lib_path = os.path.join(lib_path, 'libtest.')
...

build.sh:
...

BLD='cmake_build'
BIN='libtest.dll'

set -e  # Exit on error.
...
# Build and run.
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
cmake --build .
...

CmakeLists.txt:
...
target_include_directories(${lib_name} PRIVATE "${exec_path}")

#find_package(GMP REQUIRED)  # This line throws an error, so, I just commented it out.
if(NOT GMP_FOUND)
  set(GMP_ROOT_DIR "C:/msys64/mingw64/")
  set(GMP_INCLUDE_DIRS "${GMP_ROOT_DIR}/include")
  set(GMP_LIBRARIES "${GMP_ROOT_DIR}/lib/libgmp.a")
  set(GMP_FOUND TRUE)
endif()
target_link_libraries(${lib_name} ${GMP_LIBRARIES})

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static")
...

